# Image stabilization library Objective-C / C / C++?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opticalflow, image-stabilization

is there a decent image stabilization library (something around optical flow) out there that can give me a 3 dimensional transformation matrix to stabilize with?

I just want to stabilize a 10 frame sequence. A library with an Objective-C wrapper would be the best, but something deeper (C, C++) is more than okay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to create some simple method like -(CATransform3D)getStabilization3DTransformOfSomeImage:(UIImage*) someImage andSomeOtherImage:(UIImage*) otherImage;

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has a method for calculating Optical Flow... cvCalcOpticalFlowBM

Otherwise the following C++ code for MatLab might give you a start...

[Optical Flow in MatLab](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/)